# Is this the correct way to use async/await?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
        var execute = async (assets: DCXComposite[], session: Session) => {
            // this returns a response object with statusCode property. If the status Code is 200, it was a successful operation.
            return await session.performBatchOperation();
        };

        try {
            var assets: Composite[] = [];
            for (const project of projects) {
                assets.push(project.getComposite());

                if (assets.length === 50) {
                    var result = execute(assets);
                    assets = [];
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            Logger.error('Unable to batch delete projects', { error: err });
        }
```

Is this how to use async/await? If one of the executes fails, does the whole code fail and get thrown into the catch block? Meaning the next 50 projects do not get executed? What happens when the await throws an error?

Goal is to delete projects in batch. I'm making an API call and sending a list of 50 API projects to be deleted. If the request was a success, the execute call will return an object with statusCode = 200.

Comment: `async`/`await` syntax makes the code behave more like it's synchronous. So yes, if one of the `execute` calls fails, all subsequent projects get skipped because you're going to the catch block, exactly as it would with synchronous code in the loop. _"Is this the correct way to use async/await?"_ - that's going to depend almost entirely on what the actual _behaviour_ you want is.

Comment: Do you mean that I'm now in the catch block? You said "you're not in the catch block"?

Comment: You're never doing anything with the `result` (which is a promise btw), so no this is not the correct way to use `async`/`await`. It's unclear what you meant to do, though, so we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I added what I'm trying to do to the question. Hope that helps

Comment: How can I fix the code to make it correct? @Bergi

Comment: @ChrisHansen You probably want `var result = await execute(assets);`

Comment: Unless you're using `try/catch` in an async function, there's never a reason to `return await` a promise: just return the promise directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process your projects sequentially, stopping at the first failure, then as suggested by Unmitigated's comment, then simply `await` the call to your `execute` function (`await execute(assets);`).

In the case you want to launch *all of them* in parallel, and know if *any* of them failed, you can accumulate the returned Promises and await for the group:

```js
const allResults = [];

try {
  for (const project of projects) {
    // ...
    allResults.push(execute(/* ... */));
  }
  // Await for ALL promises to complete, or throw at first failure
  await Promise.all(allResults);
} catch (err) {
  // ...
}
```